# Get integers from textfile

Tags: java, parsing, type-conversion

Basicly I was looking for a script that puts some data of an array into a textfile, afterwards this saved data could be red in again.

I achieved to do the first part like so:

```
public void slaOp(){
    try {
        File file = new File("savefile.txt");
        // Als bestand nog niet bestaat maak je het.
        if (!file.exists()) {
            file.createNewFile();
        }
        // Schrijven naar de file
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);   
            // alle x waarden op 1 lijn en alle y waarden op 1 lijn
            String xwaarden = "";
            for(int i=0; i<positiesX.length;i++){
                xwaarden += ""+positiesX[i];
            }
            String ywaarden="";
            for(int s=0; s<positiesY.length;s++){
                ywaarden += ""+positiesY[s];
            }
    bw.write(xwaarden);
            bw.newLine();
            bw.write(ywaarden);
    bw.close();
    System.out.println("Bestand werkt correct verwerkt.");
} catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
}
}
```

This first part writes the data into a file like so:

> 123456
>
> 465489

For the second part I found many ways but not one that suits my demand.
First I had a script that red a whole line as a String. This worked except for the part that I don't need a Stringline but the numbers, seperated.

Afterwards I had tried a script that uses hasNextInt() and nextInt().
But for some reason, this script didn't read a thing. I thought that the problem would lay with the fact that the integers in the text file aren't actual integers but strings?
I couldn't resolve this problem so tried a 3th script.

```
FileInputStream fileInput = new FileInputStream("savefile.txt");
    int r;
    while ((r = fileInput.read()) != -1) {
       int c = (int) r;
        System.out.println(c);
    }
    fileInput.close();
```

This script reads characters. When a convert them to integers, the output are not the numbers that saved into the file.

Could anybody tell me the proper way of handling this situation? Are there some good explanations with examples?

Comment: If you have only one number per line, you can read the line as a string and then use `Integer.parseInt`. Would that work?

Comment: I allready tried that but I need to have the input number by number.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with @prabugp. If there is only 1 number in each line of the file, then you can read it line by line and convert each line to an Integer using [Integer.parseInt](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String%29).

At the moment I believe the reason the numbers you are getting when reading the file are not the same numbers as you have in the file is because you are converting each character in a line to its integer representation as @srm has mentioned. So you are getting the integer representation of the character '1' which is 49 for example.

To read the file line by line you can use something like the following (as explained here http://www.programcreek.com/2011/03/java-read-a-file-line-by-line-code-example/):

```
File file = new File("C:\\file.txt");

FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);

//Construct BufferedReader from InputStreamReader
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis));

String line = null;
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    // convert to integer
    Integer a = Integer.parseInt(line);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A quick solution that i can thing of, is converting string into number and then split it as you like. Although its only one thought and it could be done with many ways

a quick [link](http://java.about.com/od/understandingdatatypes/ss/Fun-With-Strings-Example-Code.htm) for you.

I can be more specific if you need help after that.

Answer (score 0):

" When a convert them to integers" how do you convert the char into an int? (keep in mind, that a char is already an int).